# How to make A Combobox in C# act like a button

Tags: c#, forms

So i was working on a project for my collage and i wanted to make the user to choose between things using a ComboBox and when he presses on the Value the Selected Value can do things like Buttons like answering things giving back text or hide text and so on and on , so how can i make it when the user Select something it acts like that ?

Comment: Assuming that you use winforms, you have to add event handler onChange to your Combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` Event, add event handler and use the new index to give the feedback you want based on the clicked item.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=net-5.0
( assuming that you work with Windows Forms )